# Raising an error in Ruby and handling it

Tags: ruby, tdd, raise

I'm doing test driven development for an assignment that's for intro to Ruby. My TestObject class is supposed to be able to be initialized with 2 parameters, a and b, but if b isn't a number then an ArgumentError should be raised. here is my initialize method, I'm not sure how to raise an exception and then handle it to prevent all of the other tests from failing as well. Any help is appreciated, my professor hasn't taught us about exceptions in Ruby yet and I haven't been able to find much help online other than trying begin, raise, rescue but that didn't work for me.

```
def initialize(a,b)
    @a = a
    @b = b

    raise ArgumentError unless b.is_a?
end
```

Comment: you want `raise ArgumentError unless b.is_a? Fixnum` if you are specific about Integers then you can do `raise ArgumentError unless b.is_a? Integer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @bjhaid said. You want to

```
raise ArgumentError unless b.is_a?(Numeric)
```

Assuming you're using testunit. In your tests use:

```
assert_raise ArgumentError do
  WhateverYourClassIsCalled.new('something', 'something that is not a number')
end
```

Comment: Please, never use `Fixnum`. They are implementation details, performance optimizations that (IMO) should never have been exposed to the programmer in the first place. (Compare with flonums in YARV 2, which are completely hidden inside the VM.) If you want an `Integer`, check for an `Integer`, but the question asks for *any* number, and so the correct class to check for would be `Numeric`. (Actually, checking for a specific *class* is never correct in OO, you should check for a *protocol*, but unfortunately that concept isn't well understood especially by people who teach OO.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag is correct.  In fact, what is it that `b` must be able to do and raise a custom error if it in fact cannot perform that behavior.  In all fairness though, you are learning Ruby, so it is valid... if you were learning OOP specifically, then the "What must it be able to do" rather than "What is it" becomes more directly relevant.

Comment: So would you advocate using the appropriate conversion function (Integer, Float) in this case, e.g.  Integer('test') => ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "test" which under the hood is calling to_int I think